# How to trigger count of colored cells using text match in another column

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to match the employee name on sheet one against employee names in sheet two, then run a count of all yellow-colored (filled) cells in a particular column.

I have a VBA module that will run the count of highlighted cells without doing a name match and it works perfectly.  Now I need to add in an additional metric of running a count of all highlighted cells for each employee.

Data Info:

> Sheet One  B2:B50  - list of employee last names.
>
> Sheet Two  D2:D1845 - column with employee last names.  Note: This is a worksheet with 1845 line items of client data records and therefore the employee name could be listed numerous times in said column.
>
> Sheet Two  E2:E1845 - column with yellow-colored cells. Not all cells in the column are colored yellow. Which is why I need a count of how many are colored for each employee.

Count by color VBA that works:

```
Function CountByColor(InputRange As Range, ColorRange As Range) As Long
   
 Dim cl As Range, TmpCount As Long, ColorIndex As Integer
   
 Application.Volatile
   
 ColorIndex = ColorRange.Interior.ColorIndex
   
 TmpCount = 0
   
 On Error Resume Next
   
 For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex _
            Then TmpCount = TmpCount + 1
   
 Next cl
   
 CountByColor = TmpCount
    
End Function
```

Comment: More specifics needed. Are you looking for a count of all cells in the E column that are yellow AND are in the same row as the name of interest from B?

Comment: Does not need to be in the same row.  This is similar to sumIf...meaning if the data in one column, matches the data in another, then enter sum value of X. However, because this is dealing with text and not numbers, and I am counting highlighted (no conditional formatting) cells and not numbers, the sumif won't work.  But that is basically what I need to do.

Comment: So if the name in B is somewhere in the D column, then sum ALL yellow cells in E?

Comment: Lance - Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you explained to me you want in the comments here's a one-liner to do what you want:

```
Public Sub NameColorCount(NameToSearch As String, TargetCell As Range, _  
           SearchRange As Range, RangeToCountColor As Range, ColorRange As Range)

  If Not SearchRange.Find(NameToSearch) Is Nothing Then
    TargetCell.Value = CountByColor(RangeToCountColor, ColorRange)
  End If

End Sub
```

If you want to do this in a cell you can use CountByColor as a UDF and use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D:D, B1)>0,CountByColor(E:E, B1),"")
```

Assuming your ColorRange is the 'B' cell, modify otherwise

Comment: Thank you SO much! This appears that it will work. But please forgive me; my brain is mush at this point.  What is my cell formula? I am not getting it right. I keep getting a #name error.

Comment: You didn't ask for a cell formula, you asked for VBA. You can probably convert the subroutine to a function and create a UDF, or you can use a worksheet function and just use CountByColor as a UDF. I had assumed you were triggering this off of a button.

Comment: My apologies, I need to get better at explaining myself. I have converted the subroutine and it is working.  Thank you again! Much appreciated.

Comment: @ExcelQuestions, I added a formula that works per cell and can be clicked and drag to autofill, using your CountByColor as a UDF.

Comment: Perfect too! I wish I could give you another green check for this added solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what you want to achieve I can't post images yet.
This Sub insert a counter in range Sheet1 C2:C50 for every employee who is in  Sheet2 D2:D1845 and the cell next to is yellow colored.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant, CountA As Integer
    Set EmployeeRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B50")
    Set CompareRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D1845")
    For Each x In EmployeeRange
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y And y.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then CountA = CountA + 1
        Next y
        x.Offset(0, 1).Value = CountA
        CountA = 0
    Next x
End Sub
```